# Add an item after a period of time in inventory, discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I need to make a bot command that produce x amount of an item when a user has got another item in the inventory, for example:

User inventory: [Iron Mine]
If the user has got the Iron Mine, a task will give in his inventory 2 pieces of iron every 20 minutes (example)

I am a beginner, i don't know how to make this thing, if you could help me i will be very grateful!

Comment: Please include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `discord.ext.tasks`

I'll give you some details but there are some good and complete examples in the docs:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html

### Basic Implementation

Basically you want to create a function that give the user [Iron Mine] (however you implemented it) and decorate it with @tasks.loop:

```py
@tasks.loop(minutes=20.0)
def give_iron_loop(self, user):
    ...
```

And then you need to actually start the loop once the user gets the Iron.

```py
# I assume you use cogs and they are class based, thus the self argument
def give_iron(self):
    ...
    self.give_iron_loop.start(user)
```

### 'Optimized' Implementation

The basic implementation might break and its highly unoptimized if your bot users are more than 1. instead, when a user gets Iron mine, you should store the time they get that somewhere (probably a dict, or a permanent storage like a database) and their user handle (you can get that with message.author, if its in `on_message` function).
You should have a main task that runs every minute and checks if any users acquisition time is now more than 20 minutes, give them what you want and store the new time and repeat the process every minute.

```py
# Assuming you store the users in a dict
@tasks.loop(minutes=10.0)
def item_check_loop(self):
    for user in self.iron_mine:
        ...
```